# I have two time series recorded on a weekly basis that have a quadratic trend. Should I difference the series twice with lag 1?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, seasonality, augmented-dickey-fuller

I have two time series on google Trends weekly data for the search of the terms 'machine learning' and 'data science'. The data can be found here http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/524910/dataScience.csv

Here's a plot of the time series in levels:
[image]
I'm not sure whether differencing the series twice is enough for ensuring stationarity.

The Augmented Dickey Fuller test (CADFtest command in R) shows that both time series are stationary when I difference them twice.

```
Augmented DF test 
                                            ADF test
t-test statistic:                          -1.283348e+01
p-value:                                    2.006856e-25
Max lag of the diff. dependent variable:    1.200000e+01
```

How to check if there's an annual seasonality (52 weeks) which would require differencing with a lag of 52? Should I just stop at differencing twice with lag 1 since the ADF test shows that the series become stationary in this case?

Comment: You should check if there is monthly seasonality by observing the 4th autocorrorelation.

Comment: What are you going to do further? What kind of model do you intend to use? @Malick, 4th autocorrelation may not work since one month has 4.35 weeks. Over a 10-year sample even the 52-weeks year may not be a very good approximation; there are 52.18 weeks in a year, so over 10 years the season will be off by nearly 2 weeks.

Comment: The 4th autocorrelation doesn't seem to be significant. I planned to do VECM since the series appear to be cointegrated (Johansen test results).

Comment: Have you tested the unit root for levels and for first differences? Although I do understand why you go for second differences -- a quadratic-looking stochastic trend may ask for it; a stochastic trend in increments (unit-root increments) may be plausible then. Also, if you are going to do VECM, then you will not need to difference at all.

Comment: True that :)
I was considering dynamic models and somehow lost track of the fact that if I'm gonna use VECM in the end, I don't even need to bother about differencing.
Thanks!